# How to calculate the Delay Formula (clarify the formula)

Tags: network, delay-differential-equations

I would like to understand how their respective answers were reached, this is a question in my current class and everyone in the class has A-Level mathematics experience - I have asked my tutor to explain but they talk very technically and I'm at a loss. I was hoping to get a simple answer from someone in this community, this formula is important to a project I am making - I am making an algorithm that sniffs packets and converts the delay result as png. I need to understand the maths behind it.

[Question w/ Answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AzwK.png)

I would like a run through of this formula, I am particularly lost with;

- On the first question, where the "50x10^3" comes from
- And the second question, why is R "64 x 10^3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You confusion relates to kilobits per second (kbs).  Since a kilobit is $1000=10^3$ bits, when the answer is expressed in bits, as these two answers are, you have to multiply kilobits by $10^3$ to get bits.

Comment: Oh I see that makes much more sense now. Is it possible to go through the formula step by step - for example what I would do on a calculator to achieve this answer

Comment: After you calculate the kbps to bits, It then moves to variable m over s, what do I do with the converted bit value at this point

Comment: Ohhh you multiple it by the result, okay I get it now thanks for your time and answer!